# now.js how to get 'now' object without browser (simple client)?

Tags: node.js, nowjs-sockets

Im playing around with node.js and now.js. Everything works fine. But i would like to make a simple client that i can run from the command-line (so without the browser).

http://nowjs.com/doc/example

In the example a HTML page gets served, and that page includes the now.js file, which creates the magic 'now' object.  But on a commmand-line there is no such thing.

For the server i have running (helloworld_server.js)

And the client helloworld_client.js i have:

```
// client.js
var nowjs = require("now");

// now i need to connect to the server (127.0.0.1:8080)
// so i i need a server object?

server = ????

var everyone = nowjs.initialize(server);

everyone.now.distributeMessage('hi!');
```

So how do i obtain the 'now' object?

Comment: I don't believe you can do this with nowjs. You may want to look into dnode. Its not the same as nowjs, but depending on your needs it may work out for you. https://github.com/substack/dnode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, got it. Once you installed now

```
npm install now
```

it creates a **node_modules** folder, inside you see folders for each extension. Deeper you find:

> ```
> ./node_modules/now/examples
> ```

and there is the **nodeclient_example** folder

> ```
> ./node_modules/now/examples/nodeclient_example
> ```

its pretty clear from there, but those curious, this is the magic you need:

```
var nowjs = require('../../lib/nodeclient/now.js');
var now = nowjs.nowInitialize('http://localhost:8080');
```

and there it it the 'magic' **now** object

make *sure* you install :

> npm install socket.io-client

otherwise it wasn't working for me!